# Textfield in Access 2003 query replaced by squares and asian symbols

Tags: ms-access, character, symbols

I am having a weird issue in MS Access 2003. I have a rather complex query, combining several tables and queries. One of these queries contains comments which are bound to a list of Orders by a Customer ID and an Order ID, but the comments when displayed are replaced by different combinations of square symbols and asian lettering, fo each comment in pairs two. The comment query itself shows the comments fine when run independently.

The "funny" thing is that I have a few options in terms of sources for these comments, but no matter which i choose the result is the same; squares and asian lettering! Even straight from a table, which has other fields that shows up fine in the query..

Is anyone familiar with this behavior, or even better has a solution?

Thanks on beforehand

-Viggo

Comment: Is the comment a memo data type? If so, see how you get on with selecting the leftmost characters (less than 255 characters)

Comment: Oh snap! I believe you've hit the head on the nail. I originally wanted to design it for multiple lines, and thus used a memo datatype.. I knew there was a reasonable explanation to be found!

Answer (score 1):

Memo data type can be a problem in a number of situations, including in complex queries. You can usually get around the problem to a certain extent by selecting just the leftmost 255 or fewer characters. The memo type need to be chosen with care.